# How to do Free hand Image Cropping in C# window application?

Tags: c#, image-manipulation

How to do Free hand Image Cropping in C# window application??

Comment: Is it winforms or WPF? Also, what control do you use for holding your image?

Comment: Refer this link...It will help you. [http://www.websupergoo.com/helpig6net/source/3-examples/5-cropimage.htm](http://www.websupergoo.com/helpig6net/source/3-examples/5-cropimage.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Okay, you provided very small amount of information, but I'll assume that you are using winforms. There are some tasks dealing with freehand-technique such as:

- Drawing
- Drag-n-dropping
- Cropping
- Selecting

They all are very similar. Let's assume that you have a PictureBox and want to crop an image inside it.

```
// Current selection
private Rectangle _cropRectangle;
// Starting point
private Point _cropStart;
// Dragging flag
private bool _isDragging;

private void pBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    _cropRectangle = new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 0, 0);
    _isDragging = true;
}

private void pBox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    _isDragging = false;
}

private void pBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_isDragging)
        return;

    _cropRectangle = new Rectangle(Math.Min(_cropStart.X, e.X),
                                   Math.Min(_cropStart.Y, e.Y),
                                   Math.Abs(e.X - _cropStart.X),
                                   Math.Abs(e.Y - _cropStart.Y));
    pBox.Invalidate();
}

private void pBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, _cropRectangle);
}
```

What happens: I make use of three mouse events (**MouseDown**, **MouseUp**, **MoseMove**) and the **Paint** event. Basically, whenever you want to do anything from the above list, you'll have handle these four events.

I tried to keep the code short and self-explanatory. There are four event handlers working with three instance fields. The fields are used to store the current state of dragging process.

Feel free to customize the code, especially the `pBox_Paint` handler. Mine just draws a thin red rectangle around selected area. You might want to do something more elaborate here.

Whenever you're done with your rectangle, you can call the `Crop` method:

```
private Image Crop()
{
    Bitmap croppedImage = new Bitmap(_cropRectangle.Width, _cropRectangle.Height);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(croppedImage))
    {
        g.DrawImage(pBox.Image, 0, 0, _cropRectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }
    return croppedImage;
}
```

It creates a new Bitmap and put the selected portion of source image into it. The returned `Image` object might be used in any manner you like.

EDIT: trying to simplify the code I made some mistakes earlier, fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Graphics.DrawImage` to draw a cropped image onto the graphics object from a bitmap.

```
Rectangle cropRect = new Rectangle(...);
Bitmap src = Image.FromFile(fileName) as Bitmap;
Bitmap target = new Bitmap(cropRect.Width, cropRect.Height);

using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target))
{
   g.DrawImage(src, cropRect, 
                    new Rectangle(0, 0, target.Width, target.Height),
                    GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}
```

**You can also refer the full code for this....
Refer this **[Link](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-image-editing-saving-cropping-and-resizing)****

Comment: I think the question doesn't carry specifically "Freehand" Freehand specifies any type of image. Please check with that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure "freehand" means "using your mouse"